# Cinnamon: How to change position of Popup notification?

Tags: customization, notification, cinnamon

I have an Cinnamon DE. After installing Google+ theme, i saw, that popup notification bar moved to the top right corner.

How to change position of it?

[image: you can see here]

Comment: can you give a screenshot?

Comment: @Anwar yeah, sure, i add screenshot. as you can see, it placed in nearly top right corner, but i want to see it in bottom right corner

Comment: What was the position before installing it?

Comment: at the bottom, in the right corner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the position of the popup notification you need to change the css file in the theme.

Please refer [this page](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-change-notifications-position-in.html) for more info.

Changing the values of

`margin-from-top-edge-of-screen: <value>px;`

or

`margin-from-right-edge-of-screen: <value>px;`

will help you to move the notification popup.

Comment: It appears that "margin-from-top-edge-of-screen" no longer works as of Cinnamon 3.0.  A new workaround can be found here: https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/4892#issuecomment-217976720